# Why isnt my promise working in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Below is my angular controller but in it, my promise doesn't seem to work. console.log isn't showing response nor is alert being shown over here.

```
myapp.controller('contrl6', ['$scope','$q','$localStorage','$http',
  function ($scope,$q,$localStorage,$http) {

    $scope.myXhr = function(){

    var q = $q.defer();

     $http({
        method: 'GET',
         url: '/api/session_data'
        })
        .success(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            q.resolve('request successful');
        })
        .error(function(response){
          console.log("error");
            q.reject('ERROR');
        });


    return q.promise;
}
console.log("hi");

var myPromise = $scope.myXhr();
  myPromise.then(function(resolve){
        alert(resolve);
        console.log(resolve);
        }, function(reject){
        alert(reject);
        console.log(reject);      
    });


  }]);
```

Comment: Are any of your `console.log()` calls showing output (even the 'hi')? If not then perhaps your code isn't wired up correctly and is never being called. Otherwise it looks as though the code should work (though it breaks a lot of the Angular conventions on how to do things).

Comment: Also, check the console network log to see whether the request is actually being sent and if so whether it succeeds or fails.

Comment: hi is showing up on console log,and how is it not according to angular conventions?

Comment: Apart from `success` and `error` being deprecated, you don't need `$q` here as you can just use the promise from `$http`. The other conventions to follow would be giving your controller a name that ends with `Controller` and using `$log` instead of `console.log()`. None of which should affect whether the code works.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `myxhr` nothing is wired together with the result of `$http`.  Don't worry about creating a new promise, because `$http` already returns one:

```
$scope.myXhr = function(){

 return $http({
    method: 'GET',
     url: '/api/session_data'
    })
    .then(function(response){
        return response;
    })
    .catch(function(response){
        throw new Error('ERROR');
    });
}
```

Comment: Getting error Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at myPromise.then

Comment: As long as you are injecting `$http` correctly and using `return` before calling `$http`, then `myPromise.then` should *always* be set to something.

Comment: God knows what the error I guess ill just wrote rest of the controller in .success function

Comment: @DavinTryon, to return the promise correctly you should change the `success` and `error` callbacks to use `then` and optionally `catch`.

Answer (score 2):

> ### Deprecation Notice
>
> The `$http` legacy promise methods `.success` and `.error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `.then` method instead.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)</sup>

```
$scope.myXhrPromise = function(){
    return (
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/session_data'
        }).then (function onFulfilled (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            //return data for chaining
            return response.data;
        }).catch (function onRejected (response) {
            console.log(response.status);
            //throw to chain rejection
            throw response;
        })
    );
};
```

Comment: Deprecated in 1.4.x and higher.

Comment: On older versions of AngularJS, the `$http` service returns promises with both the standard `.then` and `.catch` methods as well as the now deprecated `.success` and `.error` methods. There is no need to use the deprecated legacy methods when writing code for older versions of AngularJS. Use the standard `.then` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

I copy/pasted your code into a Plunkr and it works just fine once I wire it up correctly.

[Plunkr example here](http://embed.plnkr.co/ElDPJfhtMKqze6Xzg57p/)

As Duncan says, make sure you wire it up correctly, using ng-app and ng-controller. If you can update your question with the HTML markup you're using perhaps we can help further.

Comment: God knows what the error I guess ill just wrote rest of the controller in .success function